# Issue about Jsoup - fetch sub url but show main url

Tags: java, jsoup

I use jsoup to fetch the `http://live.wallstreetcn.com/` in Android. However, it shows the context of main url `http://wallstreetcn.com/`.

Why is that?

```
doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL("http://live.wallstreetcn.com"), 10000);
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
Elements es = doc.getElementsByTag("div");
Log.e("", "es:" + es);
```

Comment: i tested your code outside eclipse and it seems to work. (Jsoup 1.7.2)

Comment: Don't think this has anything to do with Jsoup. Maybe live.wallstreetcn.com is redirecting android-users.

Comment: @Christian Schneider I`m using Jsoup 1.7.2 too. Do you compare the context between subpage and mainpage. I'm not sure that you know the Chinese character.